# How can we restrict access using AWS KMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager, amazon-kms

Is there a way to import a key from a different account (lets call it ACC B: customer key) , where in I can encrypt certain data, for example, secrets manager or a particular s3 bucket where even I (ACC A) dont have access to it? The secret in secrets manager or that particular S3 bucket resides in ACC A.

Answer (score 0):

> or a particular s3 bucket where even I (ACC A) dont have access to it?

For that  case you may consider using CMK (Customer Managed Key), where the client could have necessarily permissions.  The CMK may be from different account too. (if I'm not mistaken)

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-object-encrpytion-keys/

```
You want to grant cross-account access to your S3 objects.
 You can configure the policy of a custom CMK to allow 
access from another account.
```

Another option for S3 is using the client-side S3 encryption, but then there's some overhead - the client needs to store and manage the keys itself.

> where in I can encrypt certain data, for example, secrets manager

I'm not sure if SecretManager is able to use KMS from different accounts.

To encrypt any data the client can still use KMS directly.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/wellarchitected/latest/financial-services-industry-lens/use-envelope-encryption-with-customer-master-keys.html

In this case I'd rather suggest using the [AWS Encryption API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/introduction.html) which does the same plus enforcing best practices.